# Collecting VLF information on all versions of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Based on my monitoring collection, i am having an issue while collecting info regarding how many VLF' i have for # of databases in SQL instance.

1st issue - Is there a single script which can be used from 2012 - 2019 SQL versions as standard to get the VLF info across all databases in an instance

2nd issue - how can i get 1st done with least privilege because login we use to collect info is not sysadmin and cant be. So how can i achieve this?

Much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem goes away if you solve the second with a [Signed Stored Procedure installed in Master](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver15).  If there are any version differences required, you can have different versions of the procedure for different SQL Server versions.

Then the script is a just a call to the procedure.

```
exec sp_GatherVLFStats
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem to 1 might not be solved if i am using dmv from this tip https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5008/virtual-log-file-monitoring-in-sql-server-2017/

Comment: Right.  You might have a different procedure for older versions, but the script that calls the proc is the same.

Comment: thanks but is there a way within same SP i can use that dmv and create a check for version and show results if no match then return cannot be displayed. Just trying to have one common script

Comment: In one stored procedure you can check `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` and run a different bit of dynamic SQL for each version.